# split by elements of a string, and create a dictionary with {element used to split: that chunk of text}

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, text-analysis

Consider the following text:

```
"Mr. McCONNELL. yadda yadda jon stewart is mean to me. The PRESIDING OFFICER. Suck it up. Mr. McCONNELL. but noooo. Mr. REID. Really dude?"
```

And a list of words to split on:

```
["McCONNELL", "PRESIDING OFFICER", "REID"]
```

I want to have the output be the dictionary

```
{"McCONNELL": "yadda yadd jon stewart is mean to me. but noooo.", 
"PRESIDING OFFICER": "Suck it up. "
"REID": "Really dude?"}
```

So I need a way to split by elements of a list (on any of those names), and then be aware of which one it split on and be able to map that to the chunk of text in that split. In the case of more than one chunks of text having the same speaker ("McCONNELL", in the example), just concatenate the strings.

Edit: Here is the function I have been using. It works on the example, but is not robust when I try it on a much larger scale (and isn't clear why it messes up)

```
def split_by_speaker(txt, seps):
    '''
    Given raw text and a list of separators (generally possible speaker names), splits based 
    on those names and returns a dictionary of text attributable to that name 
    '''
    speakers = []
    default_sep = seps[0]
    rv = {}

    for sep in seps:
        if sep in txt: 
            all_occurences = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(sep, txt)]
            for occ in all_occurences: 
                speakers.append((sep, occ))

            txt = txt.replace(sep, default_sep)
    temp_t = [i.strip() for i in txt.split(default_sep)][1:]
    speakers.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
    for i in range(len(temp_t)): 
        if speakers[i][0] in rv: 
            rv[speakers[i][0]] = rv[speakers[i][0]] + " " + temp_t[i]
        else: 
            rv[speakers[i][0]] = temp_t[i]
    return rv
```

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I'll add what the messy function I've tried. It does ok... it would work just fine on the example I gave, but it's not robust and sometimes doesn't align the speaker and text chunk correctly.

Comment: This isn't really splitting, it's a slightly more complicated kind of parsing than that. Also, if you really do what you're asking for, you're going to get `". yadda yadda jon stewart is mean to me. The . but nooooo. Mr. "`, and `". Really dude?"` as your output strings. Is that really what you want? If not, can you describe what you want in English? Because it'll be hard to translate to Python if you can't.

Comment: Yeah, I'm ok with the messy matching. I would probably clean it up a bit after splitting (like drop the last word if its "The", "Mr.", etc)

Comment: "is not robust when I try it on a much larger scale" is a pretty hard thing to debug. Can you give us an actual reproducible test case, with the input and expected and actual output? Or, if you can't figure out a reproducible test case, at least give us what you tried so someone else can?

Comment: Yeah, this is why I was hesitant to post my function in the first place -- I think it's harder to debug than to start fresh. Let me see if I can find a specific example that it fails on.

Comment: But the signal that something is going weird is that in the above function, sometimes len(temp_t)!=len(speakers), so I don't have a perfect speaker-to-text match each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) from standard library to define splits. Hint: split "separator" - regular expression - can be of the form:  `(WORD1|WORD2|WORD3)`

See [these examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) on what are the results of re.split.

```
import re

text = "Mr. McCONNELL. yadda yadda jon stewart is mean to me. The PRESIDING OFFICER. Suck it up. Mr. McCONNELL. but noooo. Mr. REID. Really dude?"

speakers = ["McCONNELL", "PRESIDING OFFICER", "REID"]

speakers_re = re.compile('(' + '|'.join([re.escape(s) for s in speakers]) + ')')

print speakers_re.split(text)
```

Result:

```
['Mr. ', 'McCONNELL', 
 '. yadda yadda jon stewart is mean to me. The ', 
 'PRESIDING OFFICER', '. Suck it up. Mr. ', 
 'McCONNELL', '. but noooo. Mr. ', 'REID', '. Really dude?']
```

Removing unnecessary punctuation can also be done by regexps, or simple .rstrip() and .lstrip() methods for strings.

Comment: So this will split it, but not keep track of which of the words was the split separator used in each instance

Comment: @Craig: Yes it will. When you `split` on a capturing group, you get the captured separator text in the even elements. So the only thing left to do is pairwise-iterator or -slice the list into key-value pairs.

Comment: @Craig: For example, if `s` is your initial string, and `words` is your list of words, then `pattern = '({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, words)))`, `re.split(pattern, s)` will give you the name-value pairs at elements (1, 2), then (3, 4), etc. (It'll also give you everything before the first match in element 0, which I assume you'll want to skip over.)

Comment: Perfect. Didn't realize re.split acted differently than just split. Thank you!